# One to Many join returns single row in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, crosstab

I tried to go through many pages but not able to find the result for my problem. Need solution for the below scenario, currently using left join which needs some enhancement.

for example:

[image: Click on the link to see the example]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Thanks @jarlh, i am using postgresql and here is the current query select  
t.PKID as ID, 
t.DATA as DATA, 
t.U_DATA as DATA,
t.U_VALUE as VALUE, 
from Table_1 t 
left join 
Table_2 v 
on 
t.PKID = v.PKID_FROM_TABLE_1  
where t.text = 'text';

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT PKID_FROM_TABLE_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN U_DATA = 'unique0' THEN U_VALUE END) as unique0,
       MAX(CASE WHEN U_DATA = 'unique1' THEN U_VALUE END) as unique1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN U_DATA = 'unique2' THEN U_VALUE END) as unique2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN U_DATA = 'unique3' THEN U_VALUE END) as unique3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN U_DATA = 'unique4' THEN U_VALUE END) as unique4
FROM example
GROUP BY PKID_FROM_TABLE_1;
```

This is ANSI standard SQL and will work in most databases.